# Error in formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a "Text Input" with this property:

```
Value(TextInput7_4.Text) + Value(TextInput7_8.Text) +  Value(TextInput7_11.Text)
```

It is giving me error:

> This rule creates a circular reference between properties, which is not allowed. A property cannot reference itself or other properties affected by its value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to set the `Text` property of input control based on same text input field? If yes, it it not possible in Power Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to set the `Text` property of Text Input control (one of these: `TextInput7_4`, `TextInput7_8` or `TextInput7_11`) based on the `Text` property of **same** text input control which is causing this "circular reference" rule to `Text` property.

Unfortunately, it is not supported in Power Apps formulas.

You can find similar thread for more information and possible workaround at: [Power Apps - This rule creates a circular reference between properties error](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/This-rule-creates-a-circular-reference-between-properties-error/td-p/1569501)